# Selecting lowest value of grouped column

Tags: mysql, sql

```
A         B        C
+--------+-------+----+
|    310 | 09001 | 18 |
|  80614 | 09001 | 18 |
| 169009 | 09001 | 19 |
| 201695 | 09001 | 19 |
| 282089 | 09001 | 19 |
| 320438 | 09001 | 19 |
| 131733 | 09001 | 19 |
| 387427 | 09001 | 19 |
| 404201 | 09001 | 19 |
| 525449 | 09001 | 19 |
| 605542 | 09001 | 19 |
| 710740 | 09001 | 18 |
| 746380 | 09001 | 19 |
| 867492 | 09001 | 19 |
| 864637 | 09005 | 18 |
| 710741 | 09005 | 17 |
| 746375 | 09005 | 18 |
| 556470 | 09005 | 18 |
| 604258 | 09005 | 18 |
| 401597 | 09005 | 18 |
| 141331 | 09005 | 18 |
| 336054 | 09005 | 18 |
| 387423 | 09005 | 18 |
| 203706 | 09005 | 18 |
| 278651 | 09005 | 18 |
| 126352 | 09005 | 18 |
|    312 | 09005 | 17 |
|  74627 | 09005 | 17 |
+--------+-------+----+
```

Wasnt sure how to title the question, but here's the scenario. Im looking to display 1 row for each distinct value in column B, Which is the highest value in column C, and the lowest in Column A.

For example, for 09001 It would be
169009 09001 19, and for 09005 it would display 126352 09005 18

So basically max of column C grouped by column B, and lowest value in column A of those rows.

Thanks in advance

SELECT MIN(A) AS MaxA, B, MAX(C) AS MinC
FROM Table
GROUP BY B

gives

```
310 09001   19
312 09005   18
```

not

```
131733 09001 19
141331 09005 18
```

which is what I need

`select min(A), B, C
from my_table 
where ( C) in (
select max(C)
    from my_table
    where B in (09001,09005) group by B)
    and  B in (09001,09005)
    group by B, C`

results in

310   09001   18

126352    09005   18

131733    09001   19

but there should only be one result for 09001

---

`Select min A,B
from my_table
where C in (select max(c)
from my table
where A
in (09001,
09005)group by A)
and  fips in (09001,
09005)
group by A`

ended up working, although it only shows A and B, but all I need is A for this example. Im sure there are other ways to get C to show as well.

Thanks for the help guys

Comment: but the expected results don't match with your explanation..

Comment: Why would you call a minimum of A a MaxA?

Answer (score 1):

I think you've already solved your own problem.

```
SELECT MIN(A) AS MaxA, B, MAX(C) AS MinC
FROM Table
GROUP BY B
```

Unless I made some sort of silly error there.

EDIT: I understand the requirements better now. Give this a shot.

```
WITH T1 AS (
SELECT B, MAX(C) AS MaxC
FROM Table
GROUP BY B
), T2 AS (
SELECT MIN(A) AS MinA, MaxC
FROM T1
GROUP BY MaxC)

SELECT T2.MinA AS A, T1.B, T1.MaxC AS C
FROM T1
INNER JOIN T2
ON T1.MaxC = T2.MaxC
```

Comment: I tried that, It was just selecting the max and mix on both columns, but not the min A that is of the possible rows that are max B

Comment: See if my edit gets the job done for you. Pardon the formatting.

Comment: Let me try it out now

Answer (score 0):

could you need  min over the max for B

```
  select  min(A), B, C
  from my_table 
  where ( B, C ) in (
    select B, max(C)
    from my_table 
    group by B
  )
 group by B,C
```

Comment: Close, I altered it a little and it gave me one result, not multiple

Comment: i have updated  the answer  adding group by for return one